# Trying to return a Count for three numbered sequenses,

Tags: sql, t-sql

These are loans that have "Matured".  I need a Count for loans that are 25 days after their Maturity Date, 45 days, and the Rest.  I need to assign a Label for each so I can create an iDashboard Chart.

I'm using a Subquery but I believe the data I need is located in ONE table.

----------code-------------------

```
Select z.Status, Count(z.Status)

From (Select a.Account, a.MaturityDate
Case
When datediff(dd, getdate(),[MaturityDate]) between -44 and -25 Then 'Yellow - 25 Days'
When datediff(dd, getdate(),[MaturityDate]) <= -45 Then 'RED - 45 Days'
Else 'All Good'
End As Status

From (Select * From LNSLoan a ))
Group by z.Status
```

---

```
z.Status             Count
Yellow - 25 Days     128
RED - 45 Days        56
Rest of data         1138
```

Comment: What is your question?  Your query appears to do what you need.

Comment: Why do you have `From (Select * From LNSLoan a ))` instead of `From LNSLoan a )`?

Comment: I modified code as suggested, now I'm getting this error msg.  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case'.

Comment: I'm new at this, do you recommend a book or Site that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select v.status, count(*)
from LNSLoan l cross apply
     (values (case when datediff(day, getdate(), l.MaturityDate) between -44 and -25
                   then 'Yellow - 25 Days'
                   when datediff(day, getdate(), l.MaturityDate) <= -45
                   then 'RED - 45 Days'
                   else 'All Good'
              end)
      ) v(status)
group by v.status;
```

Comment: Hmm, for cross applying a scalar expression I usually use `cross apply( select some_expr)` instead of `cross apply(values(some_expr))`. Is there any functional difference, or only up to writing preference?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis . . . I find `values()` more convenient.

Comment: Excellent.  I need to read up on Cross Apply, what a clean way of doing things.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @CesarTerriquez . . . Technically, `CROSS APPLY` implements "lateral joins".  These are very powerful and in many ways, an extension of correlated subqueries -- but correlated subqueries that can return multiple columns and multiple rows.